# Asp.Net Core update to 2.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a simple Asp.Net Core project running .Net Core 2.1 (2.1.300). I have installed Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.301 (2.1.1). What shall I do to update the project to 2.1.1?

As for now project shows within SDK dependencies `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` as 2.1.1 but `Microsoft.NETCore.App` still as 2.1.0. The latter one cannot be updated by NuGet, saying it is blocked by project.

I have already tried to edit .csproj file changing
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1.1</TargetFramework>`

but this has not worked at all. Project couldn't find any SDK references.